# Why ProblemDetails class has additional 's' in its name?

Tags: c#, class, oop, naming-conventions

We have a debate about whether it is appropriate to have `s` or plural names in a class name. So as a guidance we took a look at [ProblemDetails](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetails.cs) class which has additional `s`.

According to [this msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/use-the-correct-plural-for-the-class-name) and if I understood this doc correctly, then name should be `ProblemDetail`, not `ProblemDetails`.

Can anybody explain to me why `s` is introduced there? I just want to keep to the best practice

Comment: that's a question about the semantics of the class, which you get by reading its documentation. From my understanding the class is about errors (plural), not just one error, thus the s is completely fine IMHO. The first sentence about collections is exactly your case.

Comment: That's the name [RFC7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807#section-3.1) uses, which the class is based on.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain but I believe that this class `ProblemDetails` describes just only  one detail of one problem? Or do I miss something?

Comment: A single problem can have multiple details. If you look at the class it has a Extensions Dictionary. In the here linked rfc look at section 3.2 for an example.

Comment: Is details a phrase in English?

Comment: @shingo Don't think so. Its just whats more relevant, naming of the standard vs. naming conventions of the framework and the Asp.Net developers decides for the standard(would also be my choice when that contradicts). Interestingly the spring framework in Java valued that differently and went for the naming conventions of Java and called it ProblemDetail.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you so much for the comment! Am I correctly understood that if [ RFC7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807#section-3.1) didn't exist, then the name of this class would be `ProblemDetail` without `s`?

Comment: Generally, a plural indicates that there are many things of the same type, like a vector. With a different name, like *ProblemInfo*, the dilemma can be avoided.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain but there are other properties in this class which are not collections

Comment: well, naming conventions are just - well - conventions. You can allways break them when you have a good reason - and semnatics *is* a good reason IMHO. So when the semantics are about a collection of things, you can safely call it a plural with an `s` at the end. In that particular case that collection refers to the sum of all the properties like type, status and title (...).